# How to get position or rank of numbers in a database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rank

There is a table with fields - id, student_name, score.
How do a write a mysql/php query that will get the position
of a student based on the score field.
For example if we have scores: 60,57,80,90,85; student with score 90 will
have 1st position, 85 2nd position etc.
Two scores if equal will have same position nth, but the next score will
have n+2th position.
What does the SQL query look like?

Comment: *"What does the SQL query look like?"* - Counter  questions: What does the database schema/values look like? Have you tried something to try and solve this yourself?

Comment: Specify your MySQL version.

Comment: Wish you try to give clear explaination with better composition, also dont forget to give your code that have problem. Stay coding and be confidence to deploy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank):

```
select t.*, rank() over (order by score desc) as rnk
from t;
```

If you want this for a particular student, use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by score desc) as rnk
      from t
     ) t
where studentid = ?
```

Comment: And you guessed/wrote that within a minute?